# Why can you not set a Siri button for an external remote on Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, siri

On the latest generation Apple TVs, you can add external buttons and set which button does what. The Siri button never appears. Why does it not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote does not have a microphone to detect voice, like the Siri Remote does. It is currently unknown if you can make the Siri button programmable on a remote with a microphone.